# Categorical Scatter Plot with Dash/Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a categorical scatter plot like this:

[image: Counts of elements in discrete Locations(Wells) vs Time Points]

This is supposed to be a categorical scatter plot with discrete x values represented by counts of elements in locations(Wells) vs Time Point.

I have written this code:

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'file.xlsx')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(
    x = [df['Well A'], df['Well B'],df['Well C'],df['Well D']],
    y = df['Time Point'],
    mode='markers'
  )
)
```

And I get this as a result:

[image: Result]

Which is crazy, I have no idea what is even happening there.
Could you please help?..

P.S. My df looks like this:

[image: Dataset]

Please, help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your desired result:

[image]

```
for c in df.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Time Point'], y = df[c],
                             mode = 'markers',
                             name = c
                            )
                 )
```

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

obs = 8
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time Point': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   'Well A':np.random.randint(10, size=8),
                   'Well B':np.random.randint(10, size=8),
                   'Well C':np.random.randint(10, size=8),
                   'Well D':np.random.randint(10, size=8)})

fig = go.Figure()
for c in df.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Time Point'], y = df[c],
                             mode = 'markers',
                             name = c
                            )
                 )
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the best :) It worked!!

Comment: @mariant You're welcome! Happy to help!